# MS Band continue reading values on lockscreen

Tags: c#, microsoft-band

I try to read accelerometer values from the band even if

- The phone is locked
- The app hasn't the focus

Reading values while the app has the focus works quite well.
But if I press the "Windows" button and working on other apps, no ChangedEventArgs will be fired anymore.

I would like to collect accelerometer and gyro data over the whole day to determin what the user who is wearing the band is doing. (Pattern recognition for eating, drinking etc.)

Is this possible with the default Microsoft.Band SDK?

My code

```
            IBandInfo[] pairedBands = await BandClientManager.Instance.GetBandsAsync();
            IBandClient bandClient = await BandClientManager.Instance.ConnectAsync(pairedBands[0]);
            if (bandClient.SensorManager.HeartRate.GetCurrentUserConsent() != UserConsent.Granted)
            {
                await bandClient.SensorManager.Gyroscope.RequestUserConsentAsync();
            }

            bandClient.SensorManager.Gyroscope.ReadingChanged += Gyroscope_ReadingChanged;
            await bandClient.SensorManager.Gyroscope.StartReadingsAsync();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a TimeTrigger background task, you could explore the DeviceUseTrigger to get a "near-permanent" connection to the band. While I haven't tried it myself, below article details the necessary steps. I think it is a feasible approach considering your requirements?

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1036512/Achieveing-Indefinite-Background-Execution-with-th

Comment: Great article. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The application must be running continuously in order to stream sensor data continuously from the Band.  On Windows Phone that generally means the application is in the foreground and in active use; applications can stream sensor data in the background but, for battery life reasons, background tasks have strict limitations on the frequency and duration with which they execute.  Very few applications are allowed to operate continuously (e.g. streaming media applications).

In any case, having an active Bluetooth connection to the Band for an extended period of time would likely be a significant drain on the Band's battery.  For the sake of your users, you will likely want to identify other triggers that indicate when the user may be engaging in a particular activity, and then only streaming sensor data for those brief periods of time.

Comment: Actually thats exactly what I wanted to do. It is a pity that Windows Phone always limit the programmers. I cant use a background task, since the min-time difference between the triggers are at least 15 minutes. And if the background task triggers, I only get a limited time slide.

The project was just for scientific researches. Fast draining batteries would be fine, as long as I am able to track and analyse the data :)

Comment: You might try using the Band with the Android platform instead, as it tends to have a more "relaxed" view regarding background task execution.  (You can still use .NET and C# on Android, via the Xamarin platform and tools.)

Comment: Thats the problem MS has to face. One of several reasons why such few people want to develop for WP. It is a too closed system with nearly zero development freedom. Thats already the third APP I have to give up due the strict WP economy. But thanks for your answer.